# Speed up DB2 Data Import

Tags: load, db2

I have a 185GB data dump in 600 IXF files ranging in size from 4K to 50GB. The import command has so far done 30GB in 10hrs. I'm trying to speed up the import process and it seems the way to go is:

```
db2move newdb load
```

The problem is that I do not have the original schema so I cannot create the tables first before doing the load. Is there a way to hack the load command into creating the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using the `db2move` command; however, you can use the `IMPORT` command with the `ROWCOUNT` option to create each table and load only a single row into each table.  Use the `db2move.lst` file to determine which IXF file corresponds to each table.

Once you have created the tables with the IMPORT commands, then use `db2move newdb load` to then replace all data you've already inserted via `db2move import`:

For example, assuming `tab1.ixf` corresponds to the table `DB2INST1.TAB1`:

```
db2 "import from tab1.ixf of ixf rowcount 1 create into db2inst1.tab1"
# repeat for additional tables
db2move newdb load -lo replace
```

Comment: Please note that IBM has deprecated the use of CREATE or REPLACE_CREATE with the IMPORT and db2move commands.  IXF files may store table structure, but they are not a reliable method to migrate a schema from one database to another.  Use `db2look` instead.